# lldb breakpoint commands not working in XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

***EDIT: It now appears that it's not limited to `frame info` but in fact, NONE of the `breakpoint command add` commands work.  They will only work if typed in manually at an (lldb) command prompt***

I set some breakpoints in LLDB via the XCode console, to examine a class and how it's used in code.

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "DVLayer"
```

Breakpoint 7: 73 locations.

```
(lldb) breakpoint command add 7
```

Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.

```
 frame info

 continue

 DONE
```

This has worked fine in all previous versions of XCode going back to XCode 4.  Now however, all I get are these statements in the console, and no frame info.
I have tried the breakpoint commands on 5 different classes, and it worked on none of them... always this output.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Command #2 'continue' continued the target.

Also note that **THIS ONLY FAILS TO WORK INSIDE A `breakpoint command add` statement**

If I am simply stopped at a breakpoint in LLDB at the (lldb) command prompt, I can type `frame info` and it works as expected, however, as indicated above, adding `frame info` as a breakpoint command completely fails with the output above.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround worked for me in Xcode 8.0:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "setTitle"
Breakpoint 2: 296 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint command add --script-type python 2
Enter your Python command(s). Type 'DONE' to end.
def function (frame, bp_loc, internal_dict):
    """frame: the lldb.SBFrame for the location at which you stopped
       bp_loc: an lldb.SBBreakpointLocation for the breakpoint location information
       internal_dict: an LLDB support object not to be used"""
    print str(frame)
    frame.GetThread().GetProcess().Continue()
    DONE
(lldb) 
frame #0: 0x00000001879ca4b8 UIKit`-[UIButton _setTitleShadowOffset:]
frame #0: 0x00000001879ca4b8 UIKit`-[UIButton _setTitleShadowOffset:]
frame #0: 0x00000001879ca4b8 UIKit`-[UIButton _setTitleShadowOffset:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781ef68 UIKit`-[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781efb4 UIKit`-[UIButtonContent setTitleColor:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781ef68 UIKit`-[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781efb4 UIKit`-[UIButtonContent setTitleColor:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781ef68 UIKit`-[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781efb4 UIKit`-[UIButtonContent setTitleColor:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781edec UIKit`-[UIButton setTitle:forState:]
frame #0: 0x000000018781ee6c UIKit`-[UIButtonContent setTitle:]
```

EDIT: More info:  I could not get external python scripts going in Xcode 8.

EDIT: link to LLDB python commands: https://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your answer sooner.  Just saw it right now.  I'll give this a shot this week and give you credit (mark as answered) if it works out.  Thanks for the example.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test?

Comment: Hah, sorry mike, I haven't yet, but it is on my ToDo.  I literally have this page open in a chrome window 24/7, just to keep it on my mind.   Just really busy on this project right now, but I'll likely be able to give it a shot this weekend.  Thanks for checkin in.

Comment: Still haven't forgotten you mike.  Swear I'm going to get to it as soon as I can.  Deadlines ya know... ugh.

Comment: No worries :)  Good luck with the deadlines.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Hah, thanks for checking in, lol.  No, I seriously haven't tried it yet.  I know it will take only a few minutes.  I have so much crazy stuff going on right now, it's literally a FIFO stack of priorities I have to juggle, including being in the middle of closing on a new house in 3 weeks and preparing for all that goes along with the move.  I won't forget you though, because I really need this to work, it's going to help a lot.